# Login and Logout view not working in django auth system

Tags: python, django, session, django-authentication

I am using the Django auth system for my app. I have made a `CustomUser` table using `AbstractUser` functionality to add some more fields.

//models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):

    addr1= models.CharField(max_length=20)
    addr2= models.CharField(max_length=20)
    city= models.CharField(max_length=20)
    state= models.CharField(max_length=20)

class UserSession(models.Model):
    user= models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    session=models.ForeignKey(Session)
```

//views.py

```
from .models import UserSession
from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_in

def login(request):
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/Student_home.html')  # Redirect to a success page.
        else:
            return HttpResponse("disabled account")  # Return a 'disabled account' error message

    else:
        return HttpResponse("invalid login")  # Return an 'invalid login' error message.

def logout(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/Student_home.html')  # Redirect to a success page.

def user_logged_in_handler(sender,request,user, **kwargs):
    UserSession.objects.get_or_create(
        user= user,
        session_id= request.session.session_key
        )
user_logged_in.connect(user_logged_in_handler, sender=CustomUser)

def delete_user_sessions(CustomUser):
    user_sessions=UserSession.objects.filter(user=CustomUser)
    for user_session in user_sessions:
        user_session.session.delete()
```

//forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm 
from django import forms

class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(label="Username", max_length=30, 
                               widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'name': 'username'}))
    password = forms.CharField(label="Password", max_length=30, 
                               widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'name': 'password'}))
```

//project/urls.py(the outer one)

```
from django.contrib.auth import views
from student.forms import LoginForm

url(r'^login/$', views.login, {'template_name': 'login.html', 'authentication_form': LoginForm}, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', views.logout, {'next_page': '/login'}),
```

//login.html

```
<div class="container">
        <section id="content">
            <form action="{% url 'login' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <h1>Login Form</h1>

                <div class="imgcontainer">
                    <img src="{% static 'student/patient.jpg' %}" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">

                </div>

                <div class="username">
                    {{ form.username.label_tag }}
                    {{ form.username }}                 
                </div>

                <div class="password">
                    {{ form.password.label_tag }}
                    {{ form.password }}
                </div>

                <div class="submitb">
                    <input type="submit" value="Log In" name="mybtn">

                </div>

                <div class="resetb">
                    <input type="submit" value="Reset">
                    <a href="#forgotpwd">Forgot password?</a>

                </div>

                <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />




            </form>
        </section>




    </div>
```

//settings.py

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/login/sample'
```

The login system and authentication system is working all fine. But here is the problem. It doesn't take any action when the user can't log in (wrong username and password). But it does gets redirected to 'sample' page which I guess is dut to the thing in `settings.py`. Also the user is not redirected to any page when the user is logged out although I have specified that it should be redirected to a home page. I think the control is not getting inside the 'login' and 'logout' view. Also the sessions are also not getting deleted when a user logs out as these sessions create and delete on the 'login()' and 'logout()' functions of the django auth system.

What is wrong here?

Comment: Firstly `return HttpResponseRedirect('/Student_home.html') ` this is not correct way to use and why you need UserSession model, Django already store session of a user?

Comment: How do I store sessions and use it then? And my question still remains unanswered sir.

Comment: Which Django version are you using? because in django 1.10 authenticate method will return user object if user is_active = True and credentials should match.

Comment: django 1.8 .....

Comment: According to your question you want to redirect user if credentials not match and user is inactive right? If right then you are using HttpResponse not HttpResponseRedirect to specific URL. So your URL way is not right that mentioned in questions. You should use reverse() for URL

Comment: i don't think that is the reason..i've tried what you said..i don't think def login(request) is making any difference...can i override the login() of  django.contrib.auth.views.login by any chance?